# How to Disable Bootstrap Tool-tip on Hover ( To Not Disappears)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can you please let me know how I can stop Bootstrap Tooltip to do anything on hover like disappearing? If you take a look at following example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/ZvQ9H/1/) I have div with a tooltip located inside which appears on hover. It works fine but as when as I mouse over the tooltip the tooltip disappears!

Can you please let me know how I can force the tooltip stop behaving like this? I mean stays on until user mouse out the div(well).
I also created the green box for test and as you see as when as you mouse over the green area the tooltip disappears. so I am assuming that the tooltip also behaving like this box.

here is my code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="well well-large tooler"></div>
  <div class="well well-small span3 test"></div>
</div>
```

and js:

```
$('.tooler').tooltip({title:'Test SVG Centering', container:'.well', placement: 'top'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the bootstrap documentation for tooltips, the `container` option

> ```
> Appends the tooltip to a specific element
> ```

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

But based on your code example, `container:'.well'` does not map to a *one specific* element, because you have multiple `.well` elements in your html.

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, just removing your declaration for the `container` should be enough to eliminate the buggy hovering you discovered.

Here's a working example.

http://jsbin.com/imiqeh/1/edit

```
$('.tooler').tooltip({
    title:'Test SVG Centering', 
    container:'.tooler', 
    placement: 'top'
});
```